# How to establish Django session using Tastypie ApiKeyAuthentication?

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to use Tastypie's ApiKeyAuthentication to authenticate a request and then establish a session for the user within a Django view. I have username and api_key for the user. I do not have the user's password. This is the code I currently have:

```
class ApiKeyPlusWebAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        isAuthenticated = super(ApiKeyPlusWebAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
        if isAuthenticated:
            print request.user.email
        return isAuthenticated

#login for access from UIWebView
def login_usingApiKeyAuthentication(request):
    auth = ApiKeyPlusWebAuthentication(request)
    if auth.is_authenticated(request):
        print 'authenticated'
        login(request, request.user)
        return redirect(reverse(view_name))
    else:
        print 'NOT authenticated'
        messages.error(request, MESSAGE_INVALID_LOGIN)
        fail_redirect = redirect(reverse('login'))
        return fail_redirect
```

I am getting an error 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'. This is because I haven't called authenticate(user, password). I am using the Django default authentication backend. 
In this scenario, I only have APIKey associated with the user and don't have the raw password for authentication.

One way to handle this may be to create custom authentication backend that bypasses password requirement. However, registering a "password-less" authentication backend in settings.py seems like a hack prone to security breakdown.

So, how can I use ApiKeyAuthentication and then authenticate & login the user in Django establishing a session?

Comment: I completely don't understand. Are you saying you want to login user without password and api_key provided by them? How you login users now? Is your client on the same server where API is? If so why you want to use ApiKey? Give more background.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to set the backend in another post. You can set the custom backend directly on the user object.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """Log in to Django without providing a password.
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

@csrf_exempt
def login_uiwebview(request):
    auth = ApiKeyPlusWebAuthentication(request)
    if auth.is_authenticated(request):
        view_name = request.POST.get('view_name')
        request.user.backend = 'app.views.PasswordlessAuthBackend'
        login(request, request.user)
        return redirect(view_name)
    else:
        print 'NOT authenticated'
        messages.error(request, MESSAGE_INVALID_LOGIN)
        fail_redirect = redirect(reverse('login'))
        return fail_redirect
```